# How to solve the equation $\int_0^{t}\frac{1}{200+4(x+1)\arctan{\left(\frac{x+1}{100}\right)}}dx=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $l(x)=200+4(x+1)\arctan{\left(\frac{x+1}{100}\right)}$.

I want to find real number $t>0$ such that $s(t)=l(t)$,

where $s'(x)=\dfrac{l'(x)}{l(x)}s(x)+1$, $s(0)=0.$

It is a first order linear differential equation, and I get
 $$\int_0^{t}\frac{1}{200+4(x+1)\arctan{\left(\frac{x+1}{100}\right)}}dx=1$$.

How to compute $t$ ? 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you have any choice but numerical integrate the function
for each $t$ and throw the function to a root finder.
Following codes in `maxima` return a $t \approx 4625.55189113695$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\verb!f(t) := quad_qags(1/(200+4*(x+1)*atan((x+1)/100)),x,0,t)[1];!\\
\verb!find_root(f(t)-1,t,4600,4700);!
\end{array}$$

Comment: WA also has a root finder but I can't make it work on the integral. By manually binary search, [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[1%2F%28200%2B4*%28x%2B1%29*ArcTan[%28x%2B1%29%2F100]%29%2C{x%2C0%2C4625.5518911369}]-1) gives a $t \approx 4625.55189113690$ which differs from the `maxima` number in last digit. If you just want a number, this number will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following approach:

$$
s'(x) - \frac{4 ((400 (1+x))/(160001+2 x+x^2)+ \tan^{(-1)}((1+x)/400))}{l(x)=200+4(x+1)\arctan{\left(\frac{x+1}{100}\right)}} s(x) = 1
$$

Which is a first order differential equation, that may be solvable, by:
$$
s(x) = \frac{ \int \mu(x)dx }{\mu(x)}
$$

where $ \mu(x) $ is defined as:

$$
\mu(x) = e^{\int p(x)dx }
$$

and 
$$ 
p(x) = - \frac{4 ((400 (1+x))/(160001+2 x+x^2)+ \arctan((1+x)/400))}{l(x)=200+4(x+1)\arctan{\left(\frac{x+1}{100}\right)}} 
$$
which as ugly as it looks, can be approximated by numerical methods

Comment: At the end,do not forget to add the boundary condition.

Comment: I get $\int p(x)dx =-\int\frac{l'(x)}{l(x)}dx=-\ln{l(x)}$.

Comment: Then $\mu (x) =\frac{1}{l(x)}$.

Comment: D'Oh, ok, so $ \mu(x) = \frac{1}{l(x)}$

Comment: and $ s(x) = \frac{ \int l^{-1}(x) }{1} \cdot l(x) $, it has closed form?

Comment: Hence  $s(x)=l(x)(\int\frac{1}{l(x)}dx+c)$.  Let $\int\frac{1}{l(x)}dx=F(x)$, from $s(0)=0$, we get $c=-F(0)$ and $s(x)=l(x)(F(x)-F(0))$. Since s(t) = l(t), $l(t)(F(t)-F(0))=l(t)$. Therefore   $\int_0^t{\frac{1}{l(x)}}dx=F(t)-F(0)=1$. That is my equation.